# Integrating Facebook, after authentication loading an image prior to redirecting to the share post view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i have integrated FB to my application. When i click on the share button, i get a dialog where it says if i am `illep`, and when i click YES, it'll redirect to another view where i could type something and post to my wall.

In between the above process, after it asked if i am `illep` and after i click YES, it shows the Default.png (which i added as my loading image at start up), and then redirects to the share post in wall view.

Why is this hapenning ? I don't think i need to post any code because i have done it in accordance to the FB tutorial provided by FB it self.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the way the fb integration is implemented. The FB.app or safari is opening your app as a response to the fb URL you implemented as part of the integration. This causes your appDelegate to be called with application:openURL:... method. This causes your application to be launched, if it's not still running, and the Default.png is displayed.

Am not aware of any method to disable this behaviour, however you should note that Apple prefers your Default.png to represent the background of your application instead of a splash screen. This creates the effect that the app is more responsive. Check the UI guidelines for more details.

Comment: When i launch the application, i do get a blank screen, so i added the Default.png so that it will display it instead of the black screen. Is this wrong ? How else could i do this ?

Comment: It depends on your app.  All of Apple's examples are for simple utility apps, so their Default.png looks like the screen without any text, I.e. all the buttons and so on are included.

Comment: I have no clue to solve this. i thought Default.png only displays when the application is launched. What should i do now :S